# Deactivate automatic mark as read in Apple Mail 7.3

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I just changed from Windows to OS X Mavericks with Apple Mail App 7.3. The first thing I'm wondering about is that I cannot disable the automation to mark an email as read by default when I just clicked on it. Is there any way to do so?

I found TruePreview. But the tool does not support Mail 7.3 any more. Another solution would be to use a different mail client like Thunderbird. But there I miss the integration of the address book and the synchronisation with my iPhone and iPad.

Comment: As long you keep the preview/quick-view window open there is no way to keep the message as not read, since you did read it. You can use set- Flags for the ones you want to get back to.

Comment: Really no way? I tried TruePreview, but it is not working any more with Mail 7.3. Are there any other Plug-ins or tools available?

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5984282?tstart=0 Just click "I have this question too".

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Mail Act-On](http://www.indev.ca/MailActOn.html). It's overkill (does a lot more than just keep messages unread) and kind of pricey at $30 (with free trial), but since it's a paid app, they keep it up to date. Even when TruePreview was being maintained, it'd sometimes be weeks or months before it was updated to work with the latest version of OS X.

Comment: I'll wait for OS Yosemite and than we'll see if something in AppleMail has changed. Afterwards I will think about an alternative again...

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed in the new Mail App. :-(

Answer (score -1):

Use the standard keyboard shortcut, <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> to toggle between “read” and “unread”. You can also go to *System Preferences* → *Keyboard* to customise your own keyboard shortcut.

Comment: That's the way I'm currently using. But it's not very convinient. I even changed the shortcut to make it a bit faster to change between "read" and "unread". Is there any way to inform apple for some improvements?

Comment: @Morpheus78 The best you can do is to go to the feedback page using _Mail_ > _Provide Mail Feedback…_ from the menu.