# Mac mail prevent mark as read

Tags: mac, mail.app, email

I am working on a mac running OSX 10.10.5 and I am using Apple mail. When I am reading an email I want to prevent the email from being marked as read instantly. I would rather mark it myself, or have it wait like 2 minutes before it marks it as read.

I know about the terminal delay trick, but that doesn't work. The Truepreview plugin hasn't been updated for a long time and doesn't work anymore. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible by default, but you can download a plugin for the Mail app. The plugin is called [TruePreview](http://christianserving.org/project/truepreview). It is said that it supports OS X Mountain Lion and below, but I had it working on my Mavericks machine.

Anyway, here's the method:

- Quit the Mail app
- Download [TruePreview](http://christianserving.org/project/truepreview) (scroll down for latest versions) and run the
  installer
- Launch Mail.app and open Preferences, click on the >> arrow and
  select “TruePreview”
- Adjust the *Mark as Read* settings as desired

Have a read on [this page](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/27/change-mail-apps-mark-as-read-behavior-in-mac-os-x/) and you'll find that there is a Terminal command that can be used to delay the Mark As Read setting. However, I'm not sure you can disable it completely.

```
defaults write com.apple.Mail MarkAsReadDelay 2
```

Here, 2 is a measurement of the number of seconds to delay.

```
defaults write com.apple.Mail MarkAsReadDelay
```

The above will just revert the setting back to its default state.

[Alternatively](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132452/deactivate-automatic-mark-as-read-in-apple-mail-7-3#comments-link-145167), if you're okay with marking it as unread, an easier option would be to use a keyboard shortcut instead of manually marking as unread. The standard keyboard shortcut, which toggles “read” and “unread”, is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>. You can also go to *System Preferences* → *Keyboard* to customise your own keyboard shortcut.

Have a look, see which options takes you where, and stick with whatever is comfortable. Let me know if anything went wrong during the plugin installation (that is, if you *did* install it).

Comment: Did you even read my text? I said both the Trueview plugin and the terminal defaults trick don't work anymore

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the bottom, guess I was paying attention to something else :/ but have a look at [this page.](http://blog.macsales.com/18937-enabling-plugins-for-os-x-mail-that-stopped-working-with-10-8-4-update) 
I believe it should work.

Comment: That's okay, it happens to the best of us ;) I will try that when I get back to work tomorrow morning and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Sadly, this trick doesn't work anymore on the newer versions of Mac mail :( Thanks anyway

Comment: TruePreview plugin is not longer available. But commands works like a charm `defaults write com.apple.Mail MarkAsReadDelay 3600` just set 1 hour value that's all what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To enable this, install the add-on [Mail Act-On](https://smallcubed.com/mao/). Note: it is quite expensive at $32.00/€32,00, but there is a 30-day trial if you'd like to test it out.

After installing it, go to **Mail.app > Preferences > Mail Act-On > Message Viewing** and then you can

1. Mark a message read after a certain delay, from 0 to 30 seconds, or
2. Prevent messages from being automatically marked read at all.

It works on macOS Sierra.