# How to stop Mail from automatic "mark as read" behavior? (in Sierra)

Tags: mail.app, email, macos

I'm curious if there's a way to deactivate the feature/behavior in Mac Mail (Sierra) where mail is automatically marked as read when clicked (I want it to remain unread until I click otherwise). I know that I can use the "Classic View" to remove the preview feature, but that doesn't accomplish what I'm aiming for (I want the preview to remain active). And I know there used to be a plugin called TruePreview which offered this feature, but it's no longer available. Any ideas?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132452/deactivate-automatic-mark-as-read-in-apple-mail-7-3?rq=1

Demand for such an option seems big enough that apparently you can make good money off it (see Mail Act-On plugin).

Answer (score 1):

"Mail Act-On" by SmallCubed has a feature to "Do not mark message as read". It currently costs $30 and that is a lot if that is the only feature you plan to use (it's main purpose is to help you create advanced mail processing rules). I have used it in the past and it worked well (currently using Outlook).

Comment: +1 for this, I've used it for years and it's a life saver.  I really don't want my messages getting marked as read just because they've been selected (sometimes automatically) in the preview list!

Comment: The cost of that is now ... $60

Comment: It is crazy to pay this money for such simple functionality.